# Посоветуйте литературу по PL/SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

Ранее работал только с T-SQL в MS SQL и тут возникла необходимость познакомится с азами другой СУБД.

Какую вы литературу можете посоветовать? Быть может есть статьи, которые познакомят с PL/SQL через T-SQL, типа в T-SQL ты делал так, а в PL/SQL будь добр делать так.

В приоритете конечно же русские ресурсы. SQL SERVER был замечателен тем, что документация был русфицирована и довольна добротно. Конечно, встречался и корявый перевод, но бывало это редко.

Comment: при написании кода на незнакомом диалекте я обычно пишу гуглу что то вроде "название-фичи-в-знакомом-диалекте название-нужного-диалекта" и в 95% случаев гугл тут же дает что требуется.

Comment: @Mike, да, я с этим знаком. Однако, быть может где-то есть сравнение всех фич.

Comment: Я как-то листал книгу "SQL. Сборник рецептов" Энтони Молинаро. В ней как раз примеры на разных диалектах sql.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы рекомендовал обратиться к первоисточникам - к документации. Начать стоит с документа [Oracle Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/toc.htm), там есть раздел, посвященный PL/SQL. Далее можно прямо переходить к [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/toc.htm). Я пробовал читать разные статьи в рунете по ораклу - как правило, по тщательности изложения они уступают документации. Оракловая документация хороша тем, что там, во-первых, огромное количество примеров, а во-вторых, там довольно тщательно разбирается оракловая "Standard Library" - многочисленные пакеты с названиями `dbms_*`. Обычно книги и статьи уделяют им незаслуженно мало внимания.

Далее можно погуглить какие-нибудь списки наиболее часто возникающих вопросов при переходе с MS SQL на Oracle. Например, почему в PL/SQL надо обязательно писать `INTO` в селектах или чем оракловые временные таблицы отличаются от таковых в MS SQL.

К этому можно добавить еще одну рекомендацию Тома Кайта (цитирую по памяти):

> Если это можно сделать на SQL, делайте это на SQL. Если нельзя сделать на SQL, испольуйте хранимые процедуры на PL/SQL. Если это нельзя сделать на PL/SQL, используйте хранимые процедуры на java. Если это нельзя сделать на java, используйте хранимые процедуры на Pro C. Если это нельзя сделать на Pro C, скорее всего, вы делаете что-то не то.

Из книг, думаю, можно не глядя брать любую книгу Тома Кайта или Стивена Фейерштайна (лишь бы она актуальную версию СУБД охватывала). Они плохого не посоветуют.

Comment: Хм... Упоминание процедур на Java заставило нагуглить меня возможность использования .NET процедур и узнать, что это возможно.   .NET развивается в Oracle и по юзабельности на ровне с Java?

Comment: Про процедуры на java и Pro C я только в теории знаю, ни разу не видел, чтобы этим кто-то пользовался.  ".NET в Oracle" (что бы вы ни подразумевали под этим) - это, имхо, что-то из области фантастики (или даже "альтернативной истории").

Comment: Во, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-sps-089817.html

Comment: @iluxa1810 Что вы там такое писать собрались внутри БД, что обычного pl/sql не достаточно. При том, что даже какие то специальные возможности pl/sql не особо часто нужны

Comment: @Mike, просто, интереса ради.

Comment: @Dmitry А хорошая русская документация существует в природе? MS SQL был хорош тем, что была документация на русском, хоть временами и коряво переведенная и приходилось читать на анг.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Ваша ссылка немного про другое. Там как писать приложение на .Net для работы с ораклом - тут никаких проблем. Я про другое говорил - у оракла внутри есть как бы своя java-машина, и вы можете писать хранимки на java как на PL/SQL, и они будут движком СУБД отрабатываться.

Comment: @iluxa1810 На русском - не знаю. Терпимая, на троечку - есть. А вот чтобы вам подробно объяснили нюансы работы `pivot` или там `dbms_application_info` - не встречал. Или вот фишка с экранированием апострофа (выполните `select q'[it's cool!]' from dual`) - надо по крупицам собирать.

Comment: @Dmitry по ссылке про Net судя по картинкам создается класс на .Net, а потом разваричают на сервере Oracle и обращаются, как к обычной процедуре.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Мда, похоже на то. Не знал про такое. Но раз там .Net, есть подозрения, что это только под Windows будет работать.

Comment: @Dmitry, недавно, .NET стал мультиплатформенны и вышел .NET CORE, который и под LINUX работает => есть вероятность, что будет работать. Другое дело, зависит от того, развивают ли Oracle функционал развертывания .NET или нет.